# KDB - How to return all values in functional select with aggregation

Tags: kdb

I have a `trade` table :

```
trade:([]time:`time$();sym:`symbol$();price:`float$();size:`int$())
`trade insert(5?09:30:00.000;5?`a`b;5?10.75;5?100)
```

and aggregate(`aggr`) function :

```
aggr:{[f;c;tab]  ?[tab;();`sym;c!(f),'c] }
```

It works fine for the following :

```
aggr[(last;min;max);(`time`size`price);`trade]
```

However I want all the prices rather than just the `max`, like the following :

```
?[trade;();`sym;(`time`size`price!((last;`time);( min;`size);(`price)))]
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Hi Dave I see you have asked a few questions on this site but never accepted an answer. If you find that an answer has helped you then it is best to click on the tick beside the answer to mark as accepted. This helps other users in future easily find answered questions.

Comment: Apologies Thomas, I'll make sure to do it from now onwards. Accepted the answers for all the questions I asked earlier. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `::` [(identity function)](https://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/ColonColon) for this:

```
aggr[(last;min;::);(`time`size`price);`trade]
```

which is same as :

```
aggr[(last;min;{x});(`time`size`price);`trade]
```

`::` is overloaded to be used as monadic identity function :

```
q)(::)1
1
q){x}1
1
```